# Kotlin println() Overload resolution ambiguity

Tags: kotlin

I have this code example

```
    var n: String? = "I am nullAble"
    n = null
    var nonNullName : String = "I cannot be null"
    n?.let {
        println(nonNullName)        // 1 -- OK
        
        nonNullName = n
        println(nonNullName)       //! 2 -- Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity
        
        var v1 : String = n
        println(v1)                 // 3 -- OK
    }
```

Could anyone explain to me why the 2nd "println(nonNullName)" cannot pass the compiler, and why the 3rd "println(v1)" is OK?
Here are the error messages from IntelliJ IDEA

```
Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity:  
public inline fun println(message: Any?): Unit defined in kotlin.io  
public inline fun println(message: Boolean): Unit defined in kotlin.io  
public inline fun println(message: Byte): Unit defined in kotlin.io  
public inline fun println(message: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.io  
public inline fun println(message: CharArray): Unit defined in kotlin.io  
public inline fun println(message: Double): Unit defined in kotlin.io  
public inline fun println(message: Float): Unit defined in kotlin.io  
public inline fun println(message: Int): Unit defined in kotlin.io  
public inline fun println(message: Long): Unit defined in kotlin.io  
public inline fun println(message: Short): Unit defined in kotlin.io
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you have? I don't see any problems with it, except that the `let` block won't be called since `n` is null.

Comment: Yes, exact code. You can add it to main function. The problem happens to 2nd println(nonNullName). IntelliJ IDEA version 2020.2.3 community Edition.

Comment: my bad, I didn't realise it was a local variable. Yeah it runs fine for me too

Comment: Fascinating, this reproduces for me in the IDE but not on play.kotlinlang.org, where [it works fine](https://pl.kotl.in/ClH9HaiCz).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in an earlier version of the Kotlin type-checker, likely interacting badly with the unreachable code detection.

The error makes no sense: `nonNullName` is obviously a `String`, both because it's explicitly declared and because the IDE's type checking confirms that the explicit type is redundant.  It cannot possibly match any of the other `println` function signatures.

Removing the `n = null` line makes the error go away, which should not affect the type information of any of the variables.

Further compounding the idea that this is a bug, it [works fine](https://pl.kotl.in/ClH9HaiCz) in the official online coding environment on play.kotlinlang.org when the Kotlin version is set to 1.4.10 or 1.4.20, but breaks on Kotlin 1.3.72.

To fix it, ensure that you are on the latest version of Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the compiler is a bit confused about this code. On the one hand, you set `n` to `null` which means that the code inside `n?.let { ... }` block will not be executed. On the other hand, when you're inside the block `n?.let { ... }` it is assumed that `n` is not `null`. This creates uncertainty in the type resolution of `n` because it is considered to be `null` and `non-null` at the same time. And when you assign `nonNullName = n` this uncertainty is passed to the `nonNullName`.